# Permission error in Jupiter notebook in Windows 10 while using os library in python [Errno 13]

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

The file of my jupyter notebook and the folder I have been trying to open are in the same folder.

When running the following code (here, 'mbdataset' is the folder I am trying to open) :

`hf= open('mbdataset','r')`
`hc= hf.read()`
`hc`

I am getting the following error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'mbdataset'`

Please tell me what I should do to avoid this.

Comment: check the permission you set up for that file

Comment: @sahasrara62 I checked the `security` in it's `properties`, I don't know what name should I add  to the `Group or usernames` section , so that the access is granted, Could you please suggest me something on that?

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "mbdataset" the actual filename?

Depending on how you start your notebook, you might want to do:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

To check your current working directory. You can set your working directory with:

```
os.chdir(path_to_dataset)
```

As your comment says, you try to open a folder with `open()`

`open()` expects a file. So depending on your dataset, you might need to iterate through files, or read a json, to says this, more information is needed.

For example, you could do this:

```
import glob
files = []
for file in glob.glob("/mbdataset/*.(txt for example)"):
    text = open(file, "r")
    files.apped(text.read())
```

Comment: 'mbdataset' is the folder I am trying to open

Comment: So mbdataset is the folder containing the dataset?
open() expects a file to be opened, not a folder. Let me update my answer accordingly